# No resource identifier found for attribute 'accessibilityEventTypes' in package 'android'

Tags: android, accessibility

I am tryiing to work with accessibilityEvent with JellyBean.
I used to make it work with Android 2 but I guess they changed something in Jelly Bean.
I found something here to fix it and it is this:

In the manifest:

```
    <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityEventClass" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
       <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data
          android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
          android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>
```

And then they told me to create the fie res/xml/accessibilityservice.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                       
   android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
   android:notificationTimeout="100"
/>
```

But I get these **errors when compiling in Eclipse**:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'accessibilityEventTypes' in package 'android'
No resource identifier found for attribute 'accessibilityFeedbackType' in package 'android'
No resource identifier found for attribute 'notificationTimeout' in package 'android'
```

Any hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm..are you sure you're setting the correct target and minSDK versions? That's the only reason I usually get those type of errors

Comment: Well, I have this: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem when my Project Build Target was set too low. When I set it to 17 the error went away and I am still able to be backward-compatible with older versions of Android. [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html):

> You can still build your app to support older versions, but setting the build target to the latest version allows you to enable new features and optimize your app for a great user experience on the latest devices.

You can set your Project Build Target in Properties->Android

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I fixed changing schemas.android.com for Schemas.android.com (Capital S)

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://Schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```